# show at sign in keyboard in app

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I'm currently developing an app using jQuery mobile. I want to have the email ( @ ) sign show up in the keyboard when an input that needs an e-mailaddress is selected. I know there is a way to do this, I just don't know what to search for since none of the hits I get on google is what I want to accomplish. Is there anyone that can advice me on this? I need this for apple and also for android if thats possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was way simpler than I thought. The input type just had to be email

```
<input type="email">
```